# MediaFoundation EVR Render leak memory

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to build a media player on C# including SourceReader and EVRRender by follow the sample in https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFVideoEVR/MFVideoEVR.cpp and using MediaFoundation.Net library for my code but it leak memory when I run a long time.

With the sample in C++, It work well for a long time I test. In my code, it look similar to the code in sample C++ but leak the memory when I run a long time.
[This is my sample in C#](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hvFtDDkhy1gwdkJUSdigLcxAqfZ8Felz/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone help me?
Much appreciate for your help.

Comment: Please, share [mcve] and relevant parts of your code

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the WinRT MF API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core?view=winrt-19041? It'll be much easier than the MF extension library you're referencing.

Comment: In .NET it's not because memory grows up that you necessarily have a physical memory leak. Since you're not manually calling ReleaseComObject for every COM object you use (and sometimes, it's not so easy in .NET), you can try to regularly call GC.Collect see if it improves things. One other issue is you do a lot if byte[] allocations. If size of these is greater than 85K, they go in the Large Object Heap that is not as easy to collect as the standard heap. You might want to get rid of these and use IntPtr (but I guess this depends on the library you use)